# Send post request from android using 'ionic run android' to nodejs localhost server

Tags: node.js, rest, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using 'ionic run android' to run the ionic app on my device, connected with usb to my laptop for inspecting. I also run a node js server on my laptop's localhost:3000 port.

1) How to send requests from the ionic app that runs on my device to my server that runs on my laptop locally.
2) What is the url i need to send the request to? is it 'localhost:3000'? Is it my actual ip (x.x.x.x:3000)?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

los ,i have tried the same thing with actual android device and laptop with wifi connection.

To generate your server url:

**Step1:** bring your device and laptop or computer in the same network through wifi or wired connection.(Assume we are connected both mobile device and laptop through wifi router.If wifi router is not available we can connect our devices with wifi-hotspot of any of the devices and go on. )

**step2:** after connecting both in same network , go to terminal(`mac`) or command prompt(`Windows`) and fire `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` command respectively.

**step3:** Then find `Wireless IPv4 Address` which works as your server ip :

```
LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::781e:3ac2:6dcc:fa75%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.88
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

so in this case `192.168.43.88` is our server ip.

**Step4**:then append your server application's port number to our generated ip, as in your case `3000`

```
192.168.43.88:3000
```

**Step5:** finally as we are using our laptop as our server we can say it is our local server. So for local server we need to use `http` protocol in our url, if you are using any remote server (e.g. Amezon server) or if you deploy server on any cloud(e.g. Heroku cloud) then use `https` as protocol.
So, now our address becomes: `http://192.168.43.88:3000`

**Step 6:** Then you can attach your server endpoint name or server url where your request is handled.
e.g. `http://192.168.43.88:3000/home`

**Step 7:** Finally , in your app send request to server using something. I used JQuery Ajax request as follows:

```
var basepath="http://192.168.43.88:3000";// Put your servers ip address here. if connecting to local server use 'http' and if to remote server use 'https'

$(document).ready(function(){


$("#mybtn").click(function(e){

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:basepath+"/bots",
            success:function(data,status,request){
                //success action
            },
            error: function(error){
                //failuer action
            },
            timeout:5000
        });

});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try out https://localtunnel.me/. I wrote a short post about [how to use it](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/share-a-web-service-on-your-local-development-machine-with-localtunnel/).

TL;DR is, you install it with npm:

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

Then, start your project on some local port (for example 1337), and make sure all works well locally. Now, request a tunnel to your local server:

```
lt --port 1337
```

And you should get an output like:

```
your url is: https://awesome.localtunnel.me
```

You can use this link now and any requests to that url will be routed to your service on port 1337.